# Adding global variables via a require Common Function file

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am doing a POC on switching to Protractor and Jasmine to perform our automated scripting.  I'm trying to build a preliminary framework, but I'm having issues trying to translate my concept to reality.

I've set up three files: conf.js, spec.js, and cf.js.  Conf.js is testplan-specific configuration file, spec.js contains the actual tests, and cf.js contains the common functions that I will be using through all test plans. I am trying to include a variable in cf.js to contain the starting URL to be used in the browser.get call.  So far, I have not been able to get that to work.  I've tried declaring it in cf.js before the //commonfunctions// function declaration, as well as within the function itself. What is the proper way to do this?

cf.js

```
    var commonfunctions = function () {
      global.StartPage = 'http://google.com/';
      this.ccClick = function (clickElement) {
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(clickElement),
         this.defaultWait);



  browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(clickElement),
     this.defaultWait);
        clickElement.click();
    };
    // Common text search
      this.ConfirmText = function(testElement, compareString) {
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(testElement), 
10000);
        expect(testElement.getText()).toEqual(compareString);
      };
    };
    module.exports = new commonfunctions();
```

spec.js

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get(commonfunctions.StartPage);
  });
```

Right now, it does not navigate to the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible, I have posted a similar answer before but let me know if you have further concerns about the approach. The approach I took was to require the common function file in the onPrepare as a global variable. This way anything exported from the file is accessible throughout all the tests.

[Storing global variable in a separate file for Protractor Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132685/storing-global-variable-in-a-separate-file-for-protractor-tests/54133376#54133376)

Comment: Thank you! Switching from ASP & VBScript development to Javascript & Selenium is making my head spin.  This worked well.

Comment: I know that pain, made a similar transition myself. The mistake I made was trying to jump into Protractor without understanding any of the technologies it relies on (jasmine, NodeJS, JS, webdriver, HTML) making it extremely painful to troubleshoot. Hopefully you have learned a bit more about those than I did at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your made a mistake at following code:

```
// cf.js
var commonfunctions = function () {
      global.StartPage = 'http://google.com/';

// spec.js
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  browser.get(commonfunctions.StartPage);
});

// you define `StartPage` to a global variable, not a property of `commonfunctions`, 
thus you shouldn't refer it from `commonfunctions`, but from `global` as following:

browser.get(global.StartPage)
```

or you define `StartPage` to be a property of `commonfunctions`

```
// cf.js
var commonfunctions = function () {
   this.StartPage = 'http://google.com/';
   // use `this` at here, rather than `global`

// spec.js
beforeEach(function() {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  browser.get(commonfunctions.StartPage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below one to your `config.js`

`baseUrl: 'http://google.com/',`

To use it in your test as below

`browser.get(browser.baseUrl);`

Hope this helps you