# Protractor global wrapper functions

Tags: protractor

I want to write a globale wrapper function around protractor `browser.get`.

I tried this in OnPrepare() in config:

```
    onPrepare(){
       global.getUrl(url) =>{              
           browser.get(url);
           browser.refresh()
       });
    }
```

But then it failed saying `Property 'getUrl' does not exist on type 'Global'.`

How do you do write a global function in Protracor?

Thanks!

Comment: Your syntax is a little off. You need to use the `=` so it would be `global.getUrl = (url) =>{ browser.get(url); browser.refresh()});` Or you could declare them in another file like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314893/adding-global-variables-via-a-require-common-function-file/54316873#54316873)

Comment: I actually meant to link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132685/storing-global-variable-in-a-separate-file-for-protractor-tests/54133376#54133376)